# Co-variance of a sum with one variable appearing twice

Tags: variance, covariance

I am interested in the co-variance of two *joint* coefficients, with one variable appearing in either joint coefficient, i.e. $\mathrm{Cov}[x+z,x+w]$.

But let me start with my model, let's say I want to estimate the impact of firm size on revenue across regions. 
$y = a + b_1x + b_2 xz + b_3 xw + e$, where $x$ is firm size, $z$ and $w$ are regions dummies.

The joint coefficients are defined as:
$b_{1+2}= b_1+b_2$ and $b_{1+3}= b_1+b_3$

The sum of the variance is defined as:

$$\mathrm{Var}(x+z)= \mathrm{Var}(x)+ \mathrm{Var}(z)+2\mathrm{Cov}(x,z)$$

$$\mathrm{Var}(x+y) = \mathrm{Var}(x)+ \mathrm{Var}(w) +2\mathrm{Cov}(x,w)$$

Where it gets tricky is to compute the corresponding co-variances, I came up with:

$$\mathrm{Cov}(x+z,x+w) = \mathrm{Cov}(x+x)+\mathrm{Cov}(x+w)+\mathrm{Cov}(z+x)+\mathrm{Cov}(z+w).$$

It this correctly computed or do I miss something?

I based the equation on $\mathrm{Cov}(x+g,w+z) = \mathrm{Cov}(x+w)+\mathrm{Cov}(x+z)+\mathrm{Cov}(g+w)+\mathrm{Cov}(g+z)$. However, this does not contain twice the same variable.

Answer (score 2):

Covariances take *two* random variables as argument.

$$\mathrm{Cov}(x+z, x+w) = \mathrm{Cov}(x,x) + \mathrm{Cov}(x,w) + \mathrm{Cov}(z,x) + \mathrm{Cov}(z,w) $$

The covariance of a variable with itself equals its variance so:

$$\mathrm{Cov}(x+z, x+w) =\mathrm{Var}(x) + \mathrm{Cov}(x,w) + \mathrm{Cov}(z,x) + \mathrm{Cov}(z,w) $$